Selenium Element Not Interactable Even When Visible
I am trying to write a scraper using Selenium in Python to buy the #1 hardcover nonfiction book from the NYTimes best seller website. I am having trouble in that I can't seem to click the element I want even though I can very clearly see that it's visible.
Here's what I have so far:
driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/books/best-sellers/")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5)
time.sleep(3)
buyButton=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//section[@data-testid='section-hardcover-nonfiction']/ol/li[1]//button")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", buyButton)
buyButton.click()
wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Amazon')]")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Amazon')]").click()

This results in an "element is not interactable" error even though I can see the link on the screen.

find_element() finds the FIRST matching element on the page. Are you sure the one you're seeing is the FIRST one? You're searching for any link that contains the word "Amazon", which might match quite a few elements..

There are 55 elements on the page that match your Amazon locator. You can test this in the dev console by using $x("//a[contains(text(), 'Amazon')]").
The problem is that your locator is WAY too generic. Generally the way I handle things like this is to:

find a container element that contains each book
//section[@data-testid='section-hardcover-nonfiction']//li


find a way to locate the book you want by title, etc.
//section[@data-testid='section-hardcover-nonfiction']//li//h3[text()='SOMEHOW']


find the corresponding BUY button
//section[@data-testid='section-hardcover-nonfiction']//li[.//h3[text()='SOMEHOW']]//button


find the corresponding Amazon link
//section[@data-testid='section-hardcover-nonfiction']//li[.//h3[text()='SOMEHOW']]//a[text()='Amazon']


customize the XPath so that we can pass in the name of the book as book_name
f"//section[@data-testid='section-hardcover-nonfiction']//li[.//h3[text()='{book_name}']]//a[text()='Amazon']"



Now we put that into a short script
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
url = "https://www.nytimes.com/books/best-sellers/"
driver.get(url)

book_name = "SOMEHOW"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//section[@data-testid='section-hardcover-nonfiction']//li[.//h3[text()='{book_name}']]//button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//section[@data-testid='section-hardcover-nonfiction']//li[.//h3[text()='{book_name}']]//a[text()='Amazon']"))).click()

I tested the above script and it works... it lands on the Amazon login page.
